# How to combine document list to corpus

Tags: python

I can't combine many lists into 1 document
example of my documents like this

`['universitas', 'trunojoyo']
 ['trunojoyo', 'ada', 'diklat', 'bumi']
 ['roadshow', 'speedy', 'trunojoyo', 'isi']`

I tried it with this code but it made the tearm break apart

`' '.join(str(x)for x in documents)
 ' '.join(map(str, documents))`

and I want the results like this

`['universitas trunojoyo', 'trunojoyo ada diklat bumi', 'roadshow speedy trunojoyo isi']`

Answer (score 1):

I could not decide you want to get a list or string so the following implementation does both.

```
input_lists = [['universitas', 'trunojoyo'],
['trunojoyo', 'ada', 'diklat', 'bumi'],
['roadshow', 'speedy', 'trunojoyo', 'isi']]

output_list = []
output_string = ""

for one_list in input_lists:
    for one_element in one_list:
        output_list.append(one_element)
        output_string = "%s %s" % (output_string, one_element)
print(output_list)
print(output_string)
```

Output:

```
>> python test.py 
['universitas', 'trunojoyo', 'trunojoyo', 'ada', 'diklat', 'bumi', 'roadshow', 'speedy', 'trunojoyo', 'isi']
universitas trunojoyo trunojoyo ada diklat bumi roadshow speedy trunojoyo isi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic code to do so

```
documents=[['universitas', 'trunojoyo'],['trunojoyo', 'ada', 'diklat', 'bumi'] ['roadshow', 'speedy', 'trunojoyo', 'isi']]

documents=[" ".join(i) for i in documents]
print(documents) 

output expected by you
['universitas trunojoyo', 'trunojoyo ada diklat bumi', 'roadshow speedy trunojoyo isi']
```

Answer (score 0):

just in one line

```
[' '.join(str(word) for word in doc)     for doc in documents]
```

where

```
documents = [

['universitas', 'trunojoyo'],
 ['trunojoyo', 'ada', 'diklat', 'bumi'],
 ['roadshow', 'speedy', 'trunojoyo', 'isi'],
]
```